# How to read environment variables in JSON file using golang?

Tags: json, go, environment-variables

Is there any way to put placeholders in json file which we can dynamically fill with values?
for e.g.,

```
{
   "name": "{{$name}}"
}
```

Here, `{{$name}}` is a placeholder

Comment: That is not valid JSON. You would need to use some kind of  preprocessor.

Comment: is this possibly for reading a config file?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to achieve this by using text/template https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/

You will then be able to define json template files, for example:

```
// JSON file: user.tpl.json
{
    "username": "{{ .Username }}",
    "password": "{{ .PasswordHash }}",
    "email": "{{ Email }}",
}
```

Let's assume the following data structure:

```
type User struct {
    Username string
    Password []byte // use a properly hashed password (bcrypt / scrypt)
    Email string
}
```

To utilize the template:

```
// parse the template
tpl, err := template.ParseFiles("user.tpl.json")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// define some data for the template, you have 2 options here:
// 1. define a struct with exported fields,
// 2. use a map with keys corresponding to the template variables
u := User {
    Username: "ThereIsNoSpoon",
    Password: pwdHash, // obtain proper hash using bcrypt / scrypt
    Email: nospoon@me.com,
}

// execute the template with the given data
var ts bytes.Buffer
err = tpl.Execute(&ts, u)  // Execute will fill the buffer so pass as reference
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("User JSON:\n%v\n", ts.String())
```

The code above should produce the following output:

```
User JSON:
{
    "username": "ThereIsNoSpoon",
    "Password": "$2a$10$SNCKzLpj/AqBJSjVEF315eAwbsAM7nZ0e27poEhjhj9rHG3LkZzxS",
    "Email": "nospoon@me.com"
}
```

Your template variable names must correspond to the exported values of the data struct you pass to Execute. The example password hash is 10 rounds of bcrypt on the string "BadPassword123". Using the bytes. Buffer allows for flexible use such as passing over the network, writing to file, or displaying to console using the String() function.

For environment variables I would recommend the second approach, namely the golang map:

```
// declare a map that will serve as the data structure between environment
// variables and the template
dmap := make(map[string]string)

// insert environment variables into the map using a key relevant to the
// template
dmap["Username"] = os.GetEnv("USER")
// ...

// execute template by passing the map instead of the struct
```

Comment: text/template is certainly a viable option, but your solution is still missing support for environment variables. You should update the code to show how [Template.Funcs](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs) can be used to make os.Getenv available in the template.

Comment: Added my suggestion for dealing with arbitrary environment variables...

Comment: @Zanicar -- The solution looks pretty good. Thanks. However, do you think this would be a feasible or less complicated solution if we are dealing with large JSON objects?

Comment: @Sourav for complex structures you will probably be better off defining types that compose into large JSON objects. You will have to implement the JSON Marshaler and Unmarshaler interfaces. If you use a composite design pattern then you just call json.Marshal on the type and its subtypes to generate your large JSON structures. You will also be able to include some more refined sanity checking and validation.